# How to allow multiple email addresses on webform module?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

The version of webform module im running doesn't support sending to multiple email addresses. Ideal users should be able to add all the different emails they what to send to in one box. Dose anyone have a workaround for this. Even if that means adding the emails in a "cc" form or separating the emails with a semicolon or comma.

-Thanks

Comment: What version of webform are you using? In the email settings, you should be able to have a comma separated list of email addresses.

Comment: 7.x-3.20 I looked but I cant find that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to upgrade to the latest version of webform?

1. On your webform page, click the "webform" tab, and then the "e-mails" tab.
2. Add a single e-mail address, and click add.
3. Either click edit, or after adding an email, you should see a settings page. The first label is "E-mail to address".
4. Make sure the custom field is selected, and enter a comma separated list of emails in this field.

[image]

Comment: To specify this is from the webform module not contact. So it is a form on the page that a user can input emails. But that part of the webform doesn't support it.

Comment: The screenshot I posted is from webform. "Contact" is the name of the webform. Reading up on it, it looks like multiple emails in the "e-mail" form field are disabled on purpose to stop spamming https://www.drupal.org/node/2200587

Comment: Yeah that's what I came across to.Do you know of any similar modules that support that feature?